# GEB: driver is not set as Browser.driver

Tags: java, groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I'm writing tests with GEB and Spock (I'm new to both).

Driver is declared in GebConfig (**updated - the full config file added**):

```
import geb.report.ReportState
import geb.report.Reporter
import geb.report.ReportingListener
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager
import io.qameta.allure.Allure
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension
import org.openqa.selenium.Point
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import utils.Configuration

def logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class)

baseUrl = "${Configuration.getStringProperty("BASE_URL")}/${Configuration.getStringProperty("CONTEXT_PATH")}"

baseNavigatorWaiting = true
autoClearCookies = false
cacheDriver = false
reportsDir = 'build/test-reports'

driver = {
    WebDriver dr
    switch (Configuration.getStringProperty("BROWSER_NAME", "chrome").trim().toLowerCase()) {
        case "firefox":
        case "ff":
            dr = new FirefoxDriver(setUpFirefoxOptions())
            break

        case "google chrome":
        case "chrome":
        default:
            dr = new ChromeDriver(setUpGoogleChromeOptions())
    }

    if (Configuration.getBooleanProperty("SET_DRIVER_POSITION", false)) {
        dr.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(
                Configuration.getIntProperty("BROWSER_X_POS", 0),
                Configuration.getIntProperty("BROWSER_Y_POS", 0)))

        dr.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(
                Configuration.getIntProperty("BROWSER_WIDTH", 1600),
                Configuration.getIntProperty("BROWSER_HEIGHT", 900)));
    } else {
        dr.manage().window().maximize()
    }

    return dr
}

static ChromeOptions setUpGoogleChromeOptions() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()

    String args = Configuration.getStringProperty("BROWSER_ARGS")
    if (args) {
        Arrays.stream(args.split("\\s")).each { options.addArguments(it) }
    }
    return options
}

static FirefoxOptions setUpFirefoxOptions() {
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup()

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile()

    profile.setPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "http://,https://")
    options.setProfile(profile).setLegacy(false)
    return options
}

reportingListener = new ReportingListener() {
    void onReport(Reporter reporter, ReportState reportState, List<File> reportFiles) {
        def fileGroups = reportFiles.groupBy { it.name.split("\\.")[-1] }

        fileGroups['png']?.each {
            Allure.addAttachment(it.name, "image/png", new FileInputStream(it), "png")
        }
    }
}
```

Test example looks like (BaseTest code is added below):

```
class SimulationsRunningSpec extends BaseTest {
    def "My great test"() {
        println("test started")
        setup:
        to LoginPage

        when:
        println("when")

        then:
        println("then")
    }


     def cleanupSpec() {
        browser.quit()
        println "Clean up specification"
    }
}
```

And I get the following log sequence:

```
test started
Created driver
when
then

Created driver
Clean up specification
```

So the driver gets created when `to LoginPage` is called.

**Issue:**
It is not set as Browser driver, so when the `browser.quit()` is called, a new instance is created and then closed (the first one still is opened).

**Questions**:

1. How to set the driver to browser properly to close it then via  `browser.quit()`?
2. Am I right assuming that if I need to create a driver in **setupSpec** I can simply call `to LoginPage` there? Or what is the best way to init the driver in preconditions?

**UPDATE:**

After some debugging I found out that for some reason, browser gecomes `null` and is created again in `cleanupSpec()`. It doesn't matter whether the Spec extends Geb classes of custom base class. This reproduces my issue:

```
class TestSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def setupSpec() {
        to Page
        println "setupSpec browser: $browser"
    }

    def setup(){
        println "setup browser: $browser"
    }

    def "My first test"() {
        println("test started")

        when:
        println ''

        then:
        println ''
    }

    def cleanup() {
        println "cleanup browser: $browser"
    }

    def cleanupSpec() {
        println "cleanupSpec browser: $browser"
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
setupSpec browser: geb.Browser@4beeb0e
setup browser: geb.Browser@4beeb0e
test started


cleanup browser: geb.Browser@4beeb0e
cleanupSpec browser: geb.Browser@5c73f672
```

The last two rows show that the `browser` object  in `cleanupSpec` is different from created object in `setupSpec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, why the browser was closed before your `cleanupSpec`. Probably some other mechanism already took care of it.

The fact that you are getting a different instance in your `cleanupSpec` however is simply due to the fact, that `getBrowser` is implemented as a lazy getter. It creates a new instance if necessary, as you can see in the [code](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/GebSpec.groovy#L41-L46).

Generally you don't need to call `browser.quit` using Geb. Geb takes care of that just fine.

### Update

Here is what happens in `GebSpec` and `YourSpec`:

1. `GebSpec.setupSpec` is triggered ⇒ `_browser` is `null`
2. `YourSpec.setupSpec` is triggered ⇒ `_browser` is still `null` unless you use it here
3. `GebSpec.setup` is triggered ⇒ `_browser` is not changed
4. `YourSpec.setup` is triggered ⇒ `_browser` might be changed
5. `YouSpec`'s first feature is triggered ⇒ `_browser` is used, so it won't be `null` anymore
6. `YourSpec.cleanup` is triggered ⇒ `_browser` is not changed
7. `GebSpec.cleanup` is triggered ⇒ **`_browser` is set to `null`!** As you can see in the [code](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/GebSpec.groovy#L72-L74), `resetBrowser` is called unless `YourSpec` is `@Stepwise` and that sets `_browser` to null as you can see [here](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/GebSpec.groovy#L56).
8. `YourSpec.cleanupSpec` is triggered ⇒ `_browser` is `null` *unless you use it, so it gets reinitialized*
9. `GebSpec.cleanupSpec` is triggered ⇒ `_browser` is still `null`

Comment: No, it doesn't. At least, in my case, it doesn't close the browser after tests if I don't  call quit() method. I actually removed all the code except initializing in config and example listed here, but still the browser is not closed automatically and new instance created after calling the quit().

Comment: @BohdanN can you add your GebConfig.groovy?

Comment: Please try to add `quitCachedDriverOnShutdown =  true` to you GebConfig.groovy

Comment: Yes, tried this. It was the same behavior - new browser opened in cleanup spec. I would appreciate if someone could try the code sample a I listed in UPDATE section in my question. Adding the full geb config to the question

Comment: It seems I was not clear enough in my answer. The problem is, that you typed `browser`. When you do that, you actually call `getBrowser()` in `GebSpec`, which initializes a new browser in case there is none. Replace your `println "…$browser` with `println "…$_browser` and there will be none opening.

Comment: Year, I got it, but getBrowser() returns new one only if it is null, so the root question is why it gets null in cleanup spec

Comment: @BohdanN I updated my answer to explain your observation.

Comment: Now I see, I completely missed the code:  if (!isSpecStepwise()) { resetBrowser() } Thank you for your time and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange that you are seeing the browser reinitialise for the cleanup, what you have shown is correct.

For point 1: You are setting it correctly within the gebconfig.

For point 2:  You don't need to initialise the browser within the setupSpec(), the config entry is all you need.

The browser should close automatically once all tests are run, UNLESS you have added the following to your gebconfig and set to false:

```
quitCachedDriverOnShutdown = false
```

setupSpec() is called after all methods within the spec have been run. Is what you have shown us the only code within your spec? Is your spec extending GebSpec or GebReportingSpec or a custom base class?

The only other thing i can think is that you have 2 tests in that spec, so you're seeing "Created driver" twice, and the cleanUpSpec() is called after all tests are run so you see that called at the end. If you had called cleanup() it would run between each test.

Comment: I added some more description. I use custom BaseTest which extends GebReportingSpec